# SwiftUI run function when app has been terminated and then opened

Tags: swiftui

I recently learned how to run code whenever my app is opened by using `onReceive` and `onAppear`, as well as `scenePhase`. These work perfectly **when the app is still in the background**. However, when I terminate the app by swiping out of it after double tapping Home, and then open it, none of them work. How do I make the code run whenever the app is opened, even if it is not in the background?

Here is my code for on-open functions:

```swift
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
        switch newScenePhase {
         case .active:
          //open QR Scanner when app is resumed
          print("Active")
          return
        case .background:
          print("Background")
         return
        case .inactive:
            print("Inactive")
        @unknown default:
         return
         }
        }

.onAppear {
                print("opened!")
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
                print("opened! 2")
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
                print("opened! 3")
                
            }
```

Comment: In your many questions about this topic, you've been offered solutions already for running code on first run. Why, for example, would `didFinishLaunching...` not work for this? Another option is to run code in your `App`'s `init` method.

Comment: @jnpdx `init` or `didFinishLaunchingNotification` don't work, as I just tried, and I have already stated many times that `AppDelegate` doesn't work for me. In fact, `didFinishLaunchingNotification` doesn't seem to be run at all.

Comment: Then you need to determine *why* they don't work for you or how your situation is different. Just saying "don't work" isn't helpful -- otherwise, you'll just get the same answers you've gotten before, as clearly they are solutions that are working for other people.

Comment: How am I supposed to determine why it doesn't work? That's the whole point of asking this question. I also explained why my situation is different - **when the app is swiped out and then opened again**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has two different options for running code that will *only* run when the app is launched (eg "swiped out and then opened again").

Keep in mind that you will not see the printed lines in the debugger the second time as the debugger will not be attached to the new instance -- Xcode only attaches to the first instance that you run.

```
@objc class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("launch")
        return true
    }

}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    init() {
        print("App runs")
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Since the debugger console won't show the prints on the second launch, here's an example proving that the `init` code runs that you can see in the UI:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var appState = AppState()
    
    init() {
        print("App runs")
        appState.count += 1
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(appState: appState)
        }
    }
}

class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var appState : AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello: \(appState.count)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! My entire problem was that I was basing it on if a `print` statement ran... goes to show that `print` statements aren't everything!

Comment: @jnpdx: I do not know how your answer would solve his issue, but I believe he just mixed 3 kind of methods together without knowing which one is which and how could he take use of them, for his issue the `scenePhase` method would be perfect answer I believe.

Comment: @swiftPunk could be. I tried to present options to show the different possibilities -- you'll see why if you check the comment thread on the main question. The OP has already clarified that the main issue (which I addressed in my answer) was that `print` statements wouldn't show up in the console of unattached sessions.